# Write a single trigger in sybase for all actions insert,update and delete

Tags: triggers, sybase

I have a requirement where in I want to write a trigger in sybase when any action insert, update and delete will occur on particular table.

Syntax I know but my problem is I want to perform different action each time based on action insert , update and delete.

How can I put this condition in trigger?

like

if insert
--  perform  insert specific action

if update
-- perform update specific action

if delete 
-- perform delete specific action

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this question is about SAP/Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE). You have not stated that explicitly.

You can differentiate the behavior based on the counts of the *inserted* and *deleted* tables.

For example you can write something like this:

```
create trigger titles_trg on titles for insert, update, delete as 

declare @inserted_cnt int, @deleted_cnt int 
select @inserted_cnt = count(*) from inserted
select @deleted_cnt = count(*) from deleted

--insert command
if @inserted_cnt > 0 and @deleted_cnt = 0 
begin
    ...
end
else

--delete command
if @inserted_cnt = 0 and @deleted_cnt > 0 
begin
    ...
end

--update command
else
begin
    ...
end

go
```

Comment: Yeah I was talking about SAP only. I think this makes sense Thanks for help.